# Finding the darkest region in a depth map using numpy and/or cv2

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv, disparity-mapping

I am attempting to consistently find the darkest region in a series of depth map images generated from a video.  The depth maps are generated using the PyTorch implementation [here](https://github.com/intel-isl/MiDaS)

Their sample run script generates a prediction of the same size as the input where each pixel is a floating point value, with the highest/brightest value being the closest.  Standard depth estimation using ConvNets.

The depth prediction is then normalized as follows to make a png for review

```
bits = 2
depth_min = prediction.min() 
depth_max = prediction.max()

max_val = (2**(8*bits))-1

out = max_val * (prediction - depth_min) / (depth_max - depth_min)
```

I am attempting to identify the darkest region in each image in the video, with the assumption that this region has the most "open space".

I've tried several methods:

- #### `cv2` template matching

Using `cv2` template matching and `minMaxLoc` I created a template of np.zeros(100,100), then applied the template similar to the [docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

```
img2 = out.copy().astype("uint8")
template = np.zeros((100, 100)).astype("uint8")
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img2,template,cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

val = out.max()
cv2.rectangle(out,top_left, bottom_right, int(val) , 2)
```

As you can see, this implementation is very inconsistent with many false positives

[image]

- #### np.argmin

Using `np.argmin(out, axis=1)` which generates many indices.  I take the first two, and write the word `MIN` at those coordinates

```
text = "MIN"
textsize = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, 1, 2)[0] 
textX, textY = np.argmin(prediction, axis=1)[:2]
cv2.putText(out, text, (textX, textY), font, 1, (int(917*max_val), int(917*max_val), int(917*max_val)), 2)
```

[image: np.argmin with a hack]

This is less inconsistent but still lacking

- #### np.argwhere

Using `np.argwhere(prediction == np.min(preditcion)` then write the word `MIN` at the coordanites.  I imagined this would give me the darkest pixel on the image, but this is not the case

[image]

I've also thought of running a convolution operation with a kernel of 50x50, then taking the region with the smallest value as the **darkest region**

My question is why are there inconsistencies and false positives.  How can I fix that?  Intuitively this seems like a very simple thing to do.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Hans for the idea.  Please follow [this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tGSzM1Xne1dPOlITU7NtFUuMrn9zq3gA?usp=sharing) to download the output depths in png format.

Comment: Uncanny videos, expected some jump scare. ;-) Have you debugged some frames where you get inconsistent results? Also, could you provide some frames or videos, such that people can play around? As is, answering your question would be guesswork, I think.

Comment: @HansHirseThanks for the idea!  I updated the question with a link to a google drive folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum is not a single point but as a rule a larger area. [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) finds the first x and y (top left corner) of this area:

> In case of multiple occurrences of the minimum values, the indices
> corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

What you need is the center of this minimum region. You can find it using [`moments`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga556a180f43cab22649c23ada36a8a139). Sometimes you have multiple minimum regions for instance in `frame107.png`. In this case we take the biggest one by finding the contour with the largest area.

We still have some jumping markers as sometimes you have a tiny area that is the minimum, e.g. in `frame25.png`. Therefore we use a minimum area threshold `min_area`, i.e. we don't use the absolute minimum region but the region with the smallest value from all regions greater or equal that threshold.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

min_area = 500

for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    for i in range(img.min(), 255):
        if np.count_nonzero(img==i) >= min_area:
            b = np.where(img==i, 1, 0).astype(np.uint8)
            break
    contours,_ = cv2.findContours(b, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    m = cv2.moments(max_contour)
    x = int(m["m10"] / m["m00"])
    y = int(m["m01"] / m["m00"])
    out = cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 10, 255, 2 )
    cv2.imwrite(file,out)
```

`frame107` with five regions where the image is `0` shown with enhanced gamma:
[image]

`frame25` with very small min region (red arrow), we take the fifth largest min region instead (white cirle):
[image]

The result (for `min_area=500`) is still a bit jumpy at some places, but if you further increase `min_area` you'll get false results for frames with a very steeply descending (and hence small per value) dark area. Maybe you can use the time axis (frame number) to filter out frames where the location of the darkest region jumps back and forth within 3 frames.

[image: output for min_area=500]

Comment: thank you very much! excellent answer and I was able to follow it and get it working.  Many thanks for taking the to explain the details